# Вращение оружия вверх-вниз в 3д пространстве

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, three.js, webgl

Разрабатываем 3D шутер на ThreeJS
Оружие вращается по оси Y в зависимости от направления камеры.
Нужно также поворачивать его вверх и вниз в зависимости от того, смотрит камера вверх или вниз. Какая собственно формула должна быть?

```
weapon.rotation.set(
            controls.getObject().rotation.x,
            controls.getObject().rotation.y - Math.PI,
            controls.getObject().rotation.z
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от того, что нужно получить в итоге.

Варианты:

а) Поместить камеру в сцену, сделать объект оружия дочерним для камеры: `scene.add(camera); camera.add(weapon);`

б) Использовать [кватернионы](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Quaternion): `weapon.quaternion.copy(camera.quaternion);`